# Node.JS app is not running on heroku on user defined port number

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have made a basic application in `Node.JS`. I am trying to deploy it on heroku server which is successfully deployed.

I am able to access this application on localhost however it is not running on `heroku` server. It tries to start then it kills automatically.

**index.js**

```
var http = require("http");   
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "powerful-escarpment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**server.logs**

```
2017-04-27T15:05:52.119923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-04-27T15:05:53.414613+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-04-27T15:05:56.563672+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-04-27T15:05:56.563686+00:00 app[web.1]: > powerful-escarpment@1.0.0 start /app
2017-04-27T15:05:56.563687+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2017-04-27T15:05:56.563687+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-04-27T15:05:56.836819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-04-27T15:05:56.849642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You app fails because you are using static port`80`. By default Heroku don't give port 80(don't know why, may be because its well known). Workout is to use dynamic port number.

Here a simple app I created just now(https://infinite-savannah-21740.herokuapp.com/)

Procfile:

```
web: node index.js
```

Index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

// Server
var server = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // <== this is must

server.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.send("Working")
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port: " + port)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that's because you are defining port wrong way,It should be something like,

```
var http = require("http");   
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Actually I'm also newbie but it works for me

Answer (score 3):

Heroku sets the port your application runs on, and then binds it to port 80. To get the port Heroku sets, you need to read `process.env.PORT`:

```
const http = require("http");  

const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but see if makes a difference if you listen on port process.env.PORT || 80 instead of port 80.

```
.listen(process.env.PORT || 80);
```